# join multiple table to delete/update in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to delete user(update) I have also 8 deal table ,match table and futured table related to user table .
I want if I delete( InActive)user then must be delete all activitry from other 8 table also I have written sp but I know this is not right way to do this ....I want to use join ( or other way ) how can I do this ...Please help me ..thanks

```
   CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_DeleteUser]   
    @userId  int  
    AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON   
    SET XACT_ABORT ON    

    BEGIN TRAN    

    UPDATE  bb_user SET IsActive =0 WHERE user_id = @userId 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealA WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN
        update DealA  
        set [acq_veripro]= 'Del',[acq_status] = 'Closed',[acq_isclose] = 0,[acq_modifieddate]= Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId  
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealB WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN     
        update DealB  
        set [fundfundraise_veripro]= 'Del',[fundfundraise_status] = 'Closed',[fundfundraise_isclose]  = 0,[fundfundraise_modifieddate] = Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId 
    END  

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealC WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN          
        update DealC  
        set [provider_veripro]= 'Del',[provider_status] = 'Closed',[provider_isclose]  = 0,[provider_modifieddate] = Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId 
    END               

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealD WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN 
        update DealD  
        set [seek_veripro]= 'Del',[seek_status]  = 'Closed' ,[seek_isclose] = 0,[seek_modifieddate] = Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId 
    END          

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealE WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN 
        update DealE  
        set [lpinvestor_veripro]= 'Del',[lpinvestor_status] = 'Closed',[lpinvestor_isclose] = 0,[lpinvestor_modifieddate]= Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId  
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DealF WHERE [user_id]= @userId ) 
    BEGIN   
        update DealF  
        set [sellseek_veripro]= 'Del',[sellseek_status] = 'Closed',[sellseek_isclose] = 0,[sellseek_modifieddate] = Getdate()  
        where [user_id]= @userId         
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Match WHERE Seeker_id =@userId or  Provider_id=@userId  ) 
    BEGIN
        update Match  
        set [IsActive]=0 ,[Match_ModifiedDate]=GETDATE()  
        where Seeker_id =@userId or  Provider_id=@userId    
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Featured_Deal WHERE Deal_User_Id= @userId  ) 
    BEGIN
       UPDATE Featured_Deal
        set [Active_Status]= 0,[Modified_Date]= Getdate()  
        WHERE Deal_User_Id= @userId  
    END

COMMIT
```

Comment: Once you have deactivated the user, I don't see why it is necessary to update any other table.  But then again, I don't see why you need a separate table for each deal.

Comment: Please dont go in that way - why we have many deal table ...just want to know how to join all table for delete/update ?

Comment: Your question is really confusing.

Comment: You need a separate query for each table.  The if exists part is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ON DELETE CASCADE. IF the tables are referenced correctly it will delete corresponding rows from other tables.

Assuming you have declared @user already in original code to update the user in question?
You can Join the tables like this for the update:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

UPDATE  bb_user 
SET a.IsActive = 0,
a.[acq_veripro]= 'Del',
a.[acq_status] = 'Closed',
a.[acq_isclose] = 0,
a.[acq_modifieddate]= Getdate(),
b.[fundfundraise_veripro]= 'Del',
b.[fundfundraise_status] = 'Closed',
b.[fundfundraise_isclose]  = 0,
b.[fundfundraise_modifieddate] = Getdate(),
c.[provider_veripro]= 'Del',
c.[provider_status] = 'Closed',
c.[provider_isclose]  = 0,
c.[provider_modifieddate] = Getdate(),
d.[seek_veripro]= 'Del',
d.[seek_status]  = 'Closed' ,
d.[seek_isclose] = 0,
d.[seek_modifieddate] = Getdate()


 FROM DealA a
    INNER JOIN DealB b
    On a.user_id = b.user_id
    INNER JOIN DealC
    On a.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN DealD
    On a.user_id = d.user_id
     where a.[user_id]= @userId
```

Comment: Minus 1.  He is attempting to update, not delete records in other tables.

Comment: The code above will update the fields in the join tables not delete.

Comment: Thanks sz1 this is good i was looking for this kind of solution .... this will help me ...thanks again

Comment: No probs glad to help :)